# Deleting files associated with a database record, including when the record is deleted with a cascading delete

Tags: design-patterns, adonis.js, lucid

I'm building an application with AdonisJS.

A `User` can create `Blogs` which have `Posts` which have `PostImages`. These are tables in a PostgreSQL database, with cascading deletes on the foreign keys.

(the blog analogy is just for simplified explanation—in reality, it's a bit more complicated)

The post images are stored in an S3 bucket, with the URL stored in the `PostImage` table.

Of course, it is not ideal to have orphaned images, so when a photo is deleted in the application, an S3 delete operation takes place.

However, a record in `PostImage` can also be deleted by way of a *cascading delete* when a `Post`, `Blog`, `User` or something else is deleted.

It feels like poor design to have delete operations in every endpoint that is related to `PostImage` - this could get out of hand with distant relationships. It also feels flimsy, with a possibility of orphaned files if the operation isn't carried out on every relation.

I considered using model hooks, but due to cascading deletes being an operation that takes place at the DB-level, I don't think the related models would come into it.

Is there a better (more robust) way to do this, in AdonisJS or just generally?

Comment: Just avoid cascading deletes - I actually think cascading deletes are _dangerous_ because it will _just let you_ potentially delete _everything_ without any warning if you accidentally delete some god-object which parents everything in your database - but if you disable cascading-deletes you can still delete things - but you need to use explicit `DELETE` on each table, and being explicit is good, especially w.r.t. deleting data.

Comment: I have a similar system where I store images/videos/uploads in Azure Blob Storage (think: S3 Buckets) - except I use a content-addressable-storage model with immutable data (so a blob's name is its SHA-256 hash (so free de-duping!)) - and my RDBMS references these blobs via a `binary(32)` representation of that SHA-256 hash - but the important thing is that I never actually do hard `DELETE` ops: under normal operation things can only be soft-deleted - we only actually `DELETE` things when legally required.